# array slices (checkio) , python 3

Tags: python

```
array =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] 
def checkio(array): 
    if len(array)>0: 
        (sum (array[0:len(array):2])) * array [-1] 
    else : 
        return 0
```

The result is 0 always. What`s the problem?

Comment: You can format your code by indenting an additional four spaces, or there's a button for it in the editor.

Comment: Your function, assuming you call it correctly, can return either `0` or `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
array =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] 
def checkio(array): 
    if len(array)>0: 
        return (sum (array[0:len(array):2])) * array[-1] 
    else : 
        return 0
```

You're missing a return statement for your `if` block.